# choose a item in a database dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dropdown list populated from a database of car models in codeigniter.

When user choose the value in dropdown (e.g. Lexus, Honda, etc.) the list of cars of chosen manufacturer should load. Hovewer, nothing works. Here's my current code.

```
//controller
public function carsPage() {
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $data3['images'] = $this->model_users->getRow();
    $data['tags'] = $this->model_users->get_dropdown_tags();
    $newData = array_merge($data, $data3);
    $this->load->view('cars', $newData);
}


//model
function get_dropdown_tags() {
    //select distinct car_make from cars
    $tags = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct car_make from cars");
    $dropdowns = $tags->result();
    foreach ($dropdowns as $dropdown)
    {
        $dropdownlist[$dropdown->car_make] = $dropdown->car_make;
    }
    $finaldropdown = $dropdownlist;
    return $finaldropdown;
}
```

Comment: What part isn't working, the display of cars, or the update of your data once a selection has been made?

Comment: the update of my data once the selection has been made not working.  I choose Honda, the honda cars wont show up.  Thanks.

Comment: @Masoman, you are not trying to load the cars at all. You should either reload the whole form and display the cars (good ol' "web 1.0" way - **not recommended** at all), or make an AJAX request, read it's response and render it to the page. Both ways are way to long to explain, so please, spend 20 minutes reading about AJAX. Than come back if you have real questions.

Comment: ok, I will use AJAX, I never used it before but I will read about it and see how I can make a specific request and render it on the page.

Comment: Can I recommend Jquery for you? It's pretty easy to learn. And next time, provide Html (view) and Javascript codes to go along with questions like this. We can't tell if you are clicking a button after the select or how you expect the dropdown to trigger an action.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory about what you are trying to ask/do and this might work.

Controller:

```
public function carsPage() {

$this->load->model('model_users');
$data['images'] = $this->model_users->getRow();
$data['tags'] = $this->model_users->get_dropdown_tags();
$this->load->view('cars', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_dropdown_tags($car=NULL){

    $this->db->select('car_make');    
    $this->db->from('cars');
    $this->db->where('car_make', $car);
    return $this->db->get();

}
```

Comment: Kani, I tried that it gives me this error.  Unknown column 'distinct' in 'field list'

Comment: The model would never work except you have a column known as distinct. Add this line first `$this->db->distinct();` Change your first line to `$this->db->select('car_make');` That notwithstanding, it won't load your new dropdown unless you use some kind of full refresh or ajax. Don't get your hopes up until you embrace web 2.0

Comment: So the only way for this is through ajax?